# What methods are there to detect if large chucks of text contain a person's name?

Tags: javascript, npm, detection

Is their a way to check paragraphs of text to see if a person's name is mentioned in them, without knowing specific names to test for?

Are their any npm libraries for human name detection?

Comment: So you want to find any names in a piece of text? "Human names" is so broad, and in some cases contextual... I'd say get a list of names and search for those. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I suggest to: 1. Get a name dictionary for the language you're targeting, 2. Normalize source text, 3. Search for every name (optionally, use a fuzzy matching algorithm)

Comment: I want to build a website that consolidates news articles that will build a profile through a tagging system based off of reoccurring names.

Comment: where is the **_large chunk of text_**

Comment: It's in articles (in JSON format) of a news API I built

Comment: Look for research on [Named-Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition).

Comment: These are all helpful. Im also found this helpful so I going to leave this here for others http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/famous-people-dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a really good solution. The IBM Watson Api.

Docs https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?node#6
Demo https://natural-language-understanding-demo.mybluemix.net/

Hope this helps someone